# The bing spell check service does not correct the typos in my web app bot

Tags: botframework, spell-checking

I am using .Net V3 SDK Azure Bot framework. Integrated a Bing Spell Check API service with my Web App bot and enabled the service in my LUIS model as well. I thought the spell check service will correct the typos once the user ask the question from the bot. I am sure the spell check service works as the number of calls increase each time I test the bot, but how can I get the suggested text from the spell check service? Do I have to code this functionality in the bot code? thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "does not correct the typos in my web app bot": where? Displayed on the channel (webchat, other)?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: @NicolasR Yes, displayed on the web channel or in the test environment.
I would like to either see the misspelling corrections or word suggestions every time the user have misspelling in their questions.

Answer (score 2):

A query that's been corrected by Bing Spell Check gets sent in the LUIS result's [`alteredQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-bing-spellcheck#send-misspelled-utterance-to-luis) property.

In your LUIS dialog, you can access the `AlteredQuery` property like this:

```cs
[LuisIntent("None")]
public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    await context.PostAsync($"I think you meant \"{result.AlteredQuery}\"");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am going to play around with this. I put it in my code. Nothing different happened than before. I keep trying; It's a great suggestion.

Comment: @Breeze - Can you explain what you mean when you say nothing different happened? Are you saying the `AlteredQuery` property contains the same text as the `Query` property? You can check the value by debugging in Visual Studio or by sending the value in a message.

Comment: Yes Kyle, I am still working on it and getting use to debugging and using the emulator; I am pretty junior to VS and .NET coding.  I will keep you in the loop.

Comment: @Breeze - Can you answer the questions I asked on Feb 1?

Comment: I ended up not using it. Because it would have changed my bot to a conversational one while I am creating a qna bot. Imagine someone has typos then the bot says I think you meant [whatever the correct response was]. Then if the user says "yes" then the bot does not respond properly. What I was hoping to find was to attach a card action that has "yes", "no" buttons and it appears right after what you just suggested. Once "yes" is hit the response without typos is send to the bot.

Comment: I have another problem too. I don't think my "None" intent does anything at all. I don't see any endpoint hits on luis.ai under my Luis app.

Comment: I see. LUIS dialogs aren't designed to ask if a spelling correction is desired. You would have to code that behavior into your bot. If you have a new problem, please accept this as the answer and ask a new question.